# Spark SQL: Changing a RDD schema

Tags: apache-spark

I'm loading an RDD from a json file which contains maps
for example:

```
{"name":"daniel",
 "age":29,
  "previous_addresses":{"first_address":"123 street","second_address":"another street"}
}
```

when I'm printing the schema of the RDD I see that the previous_addresses field is a struct and I would like to store it in the parquet file as a map.

How can I achieve that?

Thanks,
Daniel

Comment: I don't think you can do this purely within Spark SQL. The easiest way to do it in regular Spark is to extract the data from the `SchemaRDD` (treating it as an `RDD[Row]`) and back out into a regular `RDD[C]` where `C` is some case class that has the representation you want. Then you need to convert it back into a `SchemaRDD` (using `sqlContext.createSchemaRDD`) and write it out as Parquet. I'm happy to work it out in more detail if you need it but it'll take time. Most of the difficulty is traversing each `Row` to convert it to your representation.

Comment: Thanks Spiro!
I actually got a response from Data Bricks saying that they will add this capability to the ApplySchema method.

Comment: That's very interesting: I was thinking of mentioning `applySchema` but the doc currently refers to it as "Developer API", which made me suspicious ... and you would still have had to transform the `Row` objects themselves, I think. I'll be curious to see exactly what functionality they end up adding and how easy it ends up being to do what you asked ...